# Допускается ли h1 заключать в div?

Tags: seo

Здравствуйте. Такой вопрос, Допускается ли h1 заключать в div ?

```
 <div class="block"><h1>Заголовок</h1></div>
```

не будет ли это негативно сказываться на сео сайта? и вообще, имеет ли это значения?

Comment: с точки зрения валидности html, то да, можно. С точки зрения СЕО, не имеет значения. Возможно, в какой то момент можно получить сиюминутную выгоду (например, потому что парсер поисковика сломался), но в целом - нет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вообще, допускается.
Но если вы просто оборачиваете один блочный элемент в другой, то это просто бессмысленно :)

В вашем случае лучше использовать `<h1 class="block">Заголовок</h1>`

На сео не влияет, главное помните - что по-хорошему на странице должен быть один заголовок **h1**

Comment: Если мне нужно 4 псевдоэлемента, то смысл есть :D

Answer (score 3):

Разумеется допускается. Я не знаю ни одного элемента H1, который не является дочерним от div - article - main. Этот элемент является одним из основных элементов для построения **[объектной модели документа DOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)**. Поисковые системы используют заголовки для индексации структуры и содержания ваших веб-страниц. **[Инфо W3 об это](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)** + **[ещё инфо W3](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp)**. Но я также согласен с ответом Николая, что в указанном вами примере кода - это бессмыслица.